# tornado.httpclient AsyncHTTPClient() python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tornado, asynchttpclient

I have a strange problem and i hope somebody encountered with it.
I'm working with TelegramAPI and i want to POST file using 
multipart/form-data. File size 32K

```
data = {'photo': open('test.jpg', 'rb').read()}
```

Using simple **requests** python lib i have no problem:

```
res = requests.post(url, files=data)
```

BUT

When i try to use

```
http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient() 

http_client.fetch(url, method='POST', body=urllib.parse.urlencode(data))
```

With the same picture

I got an error

```
tornado.httpclient.HTTPError: HTTP 413: Request Entity Too Large
```

I don't know why? **requests** works fine, but not AsyncHTTPClient, help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this [demo](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/file_upload/file_uploader.py) code. You will see there an example on how to upload files.

Answer (score 1):

The `body` argument in Tornado's HTTP client is similar to the `data` argument in `requests`. The `files` argument is something else entirely: it encodes the file using the `multipart` encoding. Which one you want to use depends on what format the server is expecting.

In this case the server is expecting `multipart` encoding, not URL encoding. Tornado does not have built-in support for generating `multipart` encoding, but as Vitalie said in the other answer, [this example code](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/demos/file_upload/file_uploader.py) shows how to do it.